# Cycle through each line in a text file with variables, batch

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to loop through each line in text file and use the contents of the line as a variable.

So far I have:

```
for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (mdbs.txt) do (
set var1=%%A
echo "%var1%" > echo1.txt
echo %var1% > echo2.txt
echo set v > set.txt
echo %%A > echo3.txt
)
```

The contents of mdbs.txt is currently:
Grounds_Maintenance.mdb

So I would expect each of the echo files to contain "Grounds_Maintenance.mdb"

However they contain:

Echo1.txt: ""

Echo2.txt: ECHO is on.

set.txt: set v

It is however looping through the files, it is just not setting the variable.

echo3.txt: Grounds_Maintenance.mdb

I must be missing something simple. I want to use a variable because I want to later on remove the extension using: set var1= %var1:~0,-4%

I'm on Windows 7. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The variable is set, but you can't access it via percent expansion inside parenthesis.

There exists a second method for accessing variables, called delayed expansion

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (mdbs.txt) do (
  set "var1=%%A"
  echo "!var1!"
)
```

Comment: `>>%out% echo "!var1!"` just prints `!var1!` for me.

Comment: @m93a Then you should enable the delayed expansion with the line `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion`

Answer (score 3):

jeb answered your direct question.

But there is no reason to assign an environment variable if all you want to do is strip off the extension. Simply use the `~n` modifier:

```
for /f "delims=" %%A in (mdbs.txt) do echo %%~nA
```

Type `help for` or `for /?` from the command prompt and look at the end of the documentation for more information about the modifiers.

Comment: Yes, this is the best solution here